# How to specify SQL Server database instance name on XA datasource in JBoss EAP 6?

Tags: sql-server, datasource, jboss-eap-6, xa

Connection properties for XA datasources in JBoss EAP 6 are configured in XA properties tab, e.g. using the **ServerName**, **DatabaseName** and **PortNumber** properties. How to specify the SQL Server database **instance name** I want the data source to connect to?

In jtds I use the pattern: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**@ServerName**/**@DatabaseName**;instance=**@InstanceName**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the **@InstanceName** should be specified as a part of **@ServerName**, as follows:

**@ServerName\\**@InstanceName

Note the double backslash is necessary while using the Admin Console Add dialog (Properties tab) - it will be automatically converted to single backslash. If a single backslash is entered, it is not possible to add the property at all (there is no warning/error message showed though).